# What does the equal ('=') symbol do when put after the method name in a method definition?

Tags: ruby

I saw this in a screencast and was just wondering what the '=' symbol does in this case.

```
def express_token=(token)
...
end
```

I would understand if it were something like this -

```
def express_token(token = nil)
```

The above (second code snippet) means setting nil as the default value of the tokens parameter. However, in the first code snippet, '=' is outside the brackets.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

That snippet defines a [Virtual Attribute](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html#UC) (or a "setter" method) so that "express_token" looks like an attribute, even though it's just the name of the method.  For example:

```
class Foo
  def foo=(x)
    puts "OK: x=#{x}"
  end
end
f = Foo.new
f.foo = 123 # => 123
# OK: x=123
```

Note that the object "f" has no attribute or instance variable named "foo" (nor does it need one), so the "foo=" method is just syntactic sugar for allowing a method call that looks like an assignment.  Note also that such setter methods *always* return their argument, regardless of any `return` statement or final value.

If you're defining a top-level setter method, for example, in "irb", then the behavior may be a little confusing because of the implicit addition of methods to the Object class.  For example:

```
def bar=(y)
  puts "OK: y=#{y}"
end
bar = 123 # => 123, sets the variable "bar".
bar # => 123
Object.new.bar = 123 # => 123, calls our method
# OK: y=123
Object.public_methods.grep /bar/ # => ["bar="]
```

Comment: can you refer to the official documentation of Ruby about defining such setter methods?

Comment: @gardenofwine: hmm, good question, I'm not sure if it's specifically documented anywhere...

Comment: +1 on the fact that setter methods inexplicably return their arguments INSTEAD of the last statement, or explicit return values. I just wasted 20 minutes on this idiosyncrasy, and this SO answer nailed it.

Comment: @gardenofwine: here's the best documentation I could find - http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html#UB

Comment: Maybe this is a naive question, but if the method looks like an attribute but it's actually a method, shouldn't the space between the variable and the equals sign break the method?

For example, method works as var=(val), but we use it as:
var = val. The space between var and = breaks the setter method...right?

Comment: Note: Contrary to popular belief, the setter _method_ still _returns_ exactly what it looks it should return (in the above example, `nil`, because that is what `puts` returns. However, the `f.foo = 123` _expression_ is different, it _evaluates_ to `123`. If you call `f.send(:foo=, 123)`, you can see that you get nil, not 123.

Comment: Is there a difference in how this syntactic sugar would be used when the said method has more than one parameter or argument?

Answer (score 21):

Those methods let you set instance vars in a more indirect way: imagine you have a class `Person`

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name

  def full_name
    [@first_name, @last_name].join
  end

  def full_name=(name)
    @first_name, @last_name = name.split(" ")
  end
end
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
p = Person.new
p.full_name = "John Doe"
p.first_name # => "John"
p.last_name # => "Doe"
p.full_name # => "John Doe"
```

Answer (score 7):

Let's take a look at the following example:

```
class NewDog  
  def initialize(breed)  
    @breed = breed  
  end

  # create reader only
  attr_reader :breed, :name 

  # setter method  
  def set_name(nm)  
    @name = nm  
  end  
end  

nd = NewDog.new('Doberman')  
nd.set_name('Benzy')  
puts nd.name
```

If you refactor the setter method to this:

```
def name=(nm)  
  @name = nm  
end
```

other programmers know that the name= method behaves as a setter method. Also as show by @maerics it behaves like a virtual attribute.

The result looks like this:

```
class NewDog  
  def initialize(breed)  
    @breed = breed  
  end  

  # create reader only  
  attr_reader :breed, :name 

  # setter method  
  def name=(nm)  
    @name = nm  
  end  
end  

nd = NewDog.new('Doberman')  
nd.name = 'Benzy'  
puts nd.name
```

Answer (score 3):

Its actually part of the name of the function. So it's a setter, in case you need separate functionality than default for getters and setters.